# How is this code correct?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have downloaded a code, it looks correct (and runs):

```
int (*oldMatrix)[NJ] = new int[NI][NJ];
int (*newMatrix)[NJ] = new int[NI][NJ];

/*  initialize elements of old to 0 or 1 */
for (i=1; i<=NI; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=NJ; j++) {
        x = rand()/((float)RAND_MAX + 1);
        if(x<0.5) {
            oldMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        } else {
            oldMatrix[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand: Why are oldMatrix and newMatrix of size NI and not of size NJ ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C++. I think the creator of the code made a mistake, shouldn't we just write int** oldMatrix = new int[NI][NJ];
int** newMatrix = new int[NI][NJ]; ?

Comment: There is also one critical error: array indices in C++ are zero-based. For an array of size `NI`, accessing the element `NI` is certainly a mistake. (For comparison, accessing `NI - 1` would not be a problem provided that `NI >= 1`.)

Comment: The code is correct (except for the out-of-bounds access) and `int** newMatrix = new int[NI][NJ];` would be a compilation error. Pointers and arrays are different things.

Answer (score 2):

```
int (*oldMatrix)[NJ] = new int[NI][NJ];
```

The `[NJ]` isn't declaring it's length there, but rather is part of its *type* declaration. `oldMatrix` is a pointer to arrays of length `NJ`, which is set to point to a dynamic array of length `NI` arrays.

It's equivalent to

```
typedef int row_type[NJ];
row_type *oldMatrix = new row_type[NI];
```

EDIT: Tested

Comment: Okay thanks. I come from C where such notation indicates that oldMatrix is of size NJ, not NI...

Comment: @user3346223 The code in question is more C like than C++ like. The best way to make a matrix IMHO is to use `std::vector` and an index function `I(i,j) = i*NJ + j`. Trying to shoehorn `[i][j]` syntax causes too many complications.

Comment: This notation is the same as C, perhaps you misunderstand the C version too. Try in C `int x[NI][NJ]; int (*p)[NJ] = x; `. If you change `NJ` to `NI` you will get a compilation error.

Comment: @Cramer, "My compiler (mingw g++) rejects both the original and the modified above" - both are fine so maybe you made a typo in your testcase or something

Comment: @MattMcNabb, must have made a typo, it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

Because NI indicates no of rows and NJ indicates no of columns.

```
                  NJ
          a1 a2 a3 a4
 NI     b1 b2 b3 b4
          c1 c2 c4 c4
          d1 d2 d3 d4
```